# Why can't java main class be protected?

Tags: java

I can create Main class with Access specifier "public" or default.

But why can't I create with protected. As default itself allowed why not protected.

Public:

```
public class MainClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 }
}
```

Default:

```
class MainClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 }
}
```

Protected:

```
protected class MainClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 }
}
```

Its showing error: 
Illegal modifier for the class MainClass; only public, abstract & final are permitted MainClass.java SCJP/src line 1 Java Problem

Comment: essentially `public` means the class is visible _outside_ its package whereas _default_ or _package_ scoped means it's only visible to other classes inside the same package. What would be the semantic of a top-level-type to be protected? Since `protected` normally refers to a feature on inheritance (being only visible to subclasses) it only makes sense for inner-classes.

Answer (score 15):

`protected` relates to giving subclasses of the containing type access to a member. There's no containing type here, so what would it mean?

Note that this has nothing to do with `main` as such... it applies to any top-level class. It *is* valid for a nested type to be protected though:

```
public class Foo {
    protected static class Bar{}
}
```

This allows subclasses of `Foo` to access `Bar`.

Comment: What is  containing type means?Can you explain with example why we can't use protected with top level class.I understand that top level class is not private because we cannot create object of that class so no make sense.

Comment: @AppKart: Containing type as in the type that contains the other - so the containing type of `Bar` is `Foo`. Basically, for *any* member of a class, `protected` grants access to that member for subclasses of the class containing the member. But a top-level class *isn't* a member of any class.

Answer (score 2):

protected or private class has no sense - as a top level class, not the inner one. Such class wouldn't be usable. Protected mean, that elements in the class can be visible by children. But what if the whole class would be package. In this case any other class could even see such class (even in the same package) until it extends such class. It would be strange and that is why it is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you compromising on the visibility of your main method by having the enclosing class as protected?
As far as I know, for a main method to be accessible there are two things you need to ensure:

1. The enclosing class is public. (I think it can be default also)
2. The enclosing class and the parent file have the same name.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: (1) Since the enclosing class must top-level it can only be public or package-private.  Both work. (2) It is not necessary for the enclosing class to have the same name as the parent file.

Comment: as u said enclosing class can be public or default. But protected is b/w public and default write. so why can't we suppose to use it..

Comment: @santose: Protected is only visible to the children of that class. Main class is an entry point to the program, where the execution begins, so it has to be public. Only then can external entities (i.e. they system) see it and use it.

Comment: @Sagar V, the system - aka the JRE - can see everything - public, protected, package-private, and private.  I don't see why u couldn't implement a JRE that accepts a private main method.  So these things are arbitrary.

Comment: @Sagar V, ur thngs is correct, thn how default class is working. Default class has lesser privileage thn protected rite..

Comment: Protected is just like private, except it is visible to its children. Default (package) access is still visible within the same package. An external object can't use a private method. A protected method can only be used by the children of a certain class.

Comment: @emory: I didn't understand the last comment. The JVM starts accessing the program via its main method and this is also why we keep it as public and static: public so that it is visible to all objects and static so that we don't need to create an object of the class to run it. I'm sorry if I've misunderstood your comment.